# Measure CPU, Disk (I/O) and Memory Used by a Specific Database

Tags: sql-server, migration

For reasons outside the scope of this question, I need to deploy a specific database from my main server to a secondary server; the problem I have is that the secondary server does not exist yet and I need to purchase it.

The thing is, how can I measure the CPU, IO and Memory used by this specific database in order to buy a server capable of handling the load of this specific database in the same (or less) time than the current server?

Any guidance on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is this database?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik 600gb

Comment: Okay, and what's the server like that it's on today? Are users complaining about performance?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik There are ups and downs, the thing is we have running like 20 databases in the main server, sometimes the operation of each overlaps, this is when some tasks increase their time several times. I must add, the main type of task the database performs is data processing (I think it's called OLAP processing), this instead of OLTP (small IO operations)

Comment: What I'm getting at is that if performance is generally okay now, I'd stick it on another server of the same size, and take advantage of the isolation. There's not really a good way to measure any of the specific metrics you want. You'll go out and find scripts that say they'll tell you how much CPU each database uses, or what objects are in memory, but they're only snapshots, they're not long term. I'd start by looking at your server's wait stats to see if there are any general resource bottlenecks, and then buy hardware to compensate for those.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I see. Do you know if there is third party software that could measure this? - maybe installing an agent in the server and complimenting that with DMVs?

Comment: Sentry One Performance Advisor is a good choice for this type of monitoring.

Comment: You can get file stats and the breakdown of cache usage per database, so if you monitor it over time you can get a rough idea. The CPU is trickier, because in general it's the queries using it, not the database.

Comment: @dean would you mind posting an aswer telling me how?